# How to conditionally exclude a scenario in cucumber

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to exclude scenarios programmatically in cucumber. Testcases are OS dependent in my case. Say if underlying OS is Windows, I would like to skip certain scenarios. After some research on google I found out that there a place where you can hook up this logic in ruby i.e. `AfterConfiguration`. However, I am not able to find where I can hook this up to cucumber through scala.
I am also aware that it is not good practice to exclude scenarios but I have no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add tags for the os-dependent scenarios (this can be at a feature file level by putting the tag at the top of the file).

```
@windows8
Scenario: Seeing extra feature XYZ in Windows 8
```

Then cucumber options that only use the tags for that os, or that ignore the tags for the other os. If you are using mvn, it might look like this:

```
mvn clean install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @windows8"
```

Comment: Where exactly can I define these profiles in a scala based application

Comment: I am not sure what type of builder you are using. I updated it because you probably are not using ruby cukes. I guessed that you are using mvn.

Comment: I am using SBT. I can try to do the same.